# Java&Mongo: get object where field exist

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Situation:
I have collection with documents, each document contains such fields: "_id"(ObjectId), "userId"(String), but it also can be field "files"(Object).

When I'm doing this:

```
final Query query = new Query();           
query.fields().include("_id");           

final List<File> fileList = mongo.find(query, File.class);
```

As a result I'm getting `fileList` with all records and that is fine.

But when I'm doing like that, to get records only where "files" field exists - result is error.

```
final Query query = new Query();           
query.fields().include("files");           

final List<File> fileList = mongo.find(query, File.class);
```

Does error occur because  I'm trying to get Object field? And how I can solve this with Query or Criteria?

Comment: What is your intention on 2nd query? Do you want retrieve all documents that contains `files` field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct this `Query` to get all documents that contains `files` filed:

```
Query.query(Criteria.where("files").exists(true))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query` annotation on your method (useful when using `MongoRepository`):

```
@Query(value="{ files : { $exists : true } }")
```